# What is the best solution to re run failed plugins in CRM

Tags: c#, plugins, ssis, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

For sometime, I have been struggling to find a good solution to re run a failed plugin (on CRM 2011 On premise). I have series of plugins that runs on Create. Primarily they push the newly created record in to our old system using WCF and stored procedures.

When this plugin fails (Always because of non code related issue i.e. server being down), currently I am running a SSIS package manually to push this failed record in to the old system. While this is working it is not the most practical thing.

Is there a way that I can re-run the same Create plugin without having to re-create the same record?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your plugin into a `CodeActivity` and create a workflow that is triggered on the Create message and that can be started on demand as well.

Comment: I would do this too... you can resume workflows from the last step which failed